# convert to mysql datetime

Tags: php, date, time

pls i want to convert this 06-29-2010 04:00PM to this format Y-m-d h:i:s in php

thanks

Comment: where did the input `06-29-2010 04:00PM` come from?

Comment: from html to php through POST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)**:

```
$date  = '06-29-2010 04:00PM';
$date  = str_replace('-', '/', $date);
echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($date));
```

**Result:**

```
2010-06-29 04:00:00
```

Comment: Error
converting this 06-21-2010 05:00PM gives me this 1970-01-01 01:00:00.
any ideas

Comment: @Smith: See my updated answer please, that was because of `-` in the date.

Comment: You guys are so fast. In less that 30mins I get many questions answered. why do you guys help so quickly, are you paid? am a developer too.
Great job!

Comment: @Smith: It is great pleasure to help others all volunteer (no pay). Also we learn a lot here at this great site :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll go ahead and offer [PHP's date() manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)  as a second resource.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to convert one timestamp or check your calculations you can use a web tool like www.unixstamp.com (just keep in mind it uses GMT)